# Mathematical sound way to rediscretize a distribution

Tags: distributions, discrete-data

Case:
I have a discrete distribution with a certain interval level. I want to rediscretize it so that the interval level is reduced, but the general characteristics of the distribution remain intact.

Example:
I have a discrete distribution with 10 elements, ie:
x= 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
y= 0  1  4  9  16 25 36 49 64 81

Now I want to reduce this, so that I am left with, say, 6 elements with the same range of x:
x= 0  ..  ..  ..  ..  9
y= ...

My Question:
Is there established (and easily understood) mathematical theory/methods to accomplish this? And where can I find this (incl. simple examples)?

My initial thoughts:
Apply a kind of percentile approach relating to the number of new elements I wish to have in the new discrete distribution. Ie, if I want 5-elements, then maybe take the 0th, 25th, 50th, 75th and 100th percentile of the original distibution. (BUT... I havent found any proven theory supporting this approach)

Comment: Could you please explain the sense in which your `x` and `y` values define a single "distribution"? Usually, in statistics a discrete distribution will be specified by a collection of probabilities, one per possible value, and the probabilities must be non-negative and sum to unity. It is puzzling that your numbers do not have these properties.

Comment: Perhaps you mean that your $x$'s are categories and your $y$'s are counts? That's the only way I can make sense of this.

Comment: Discretizing a discrete distribution is easy: just apply summation! Can you define "general characteristics"?

Comment: It is as Wayne says: the x's are the 'bins' if you like. The y's are the values or counts in those bins. You can also see it as the x and y axes of a CDF in which the y-values require division by the sum of the y-values. The question is: how to rediscretizae this so that the bins are i.e. x=0 3 6 9, and y= ? ? ?.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What is your ultimate objective? Maybe then we can see some other way to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this question as well and have not found any good or well established answers.  Part of the issue depends on what characteristics of the distribution you want to preserve.

To preserve the mean and general "shape" of the distribution, there is a method that uses linear interpolation.  However, this method does not preserve variance.

The idea is the proportion associated with a point in your original x scale, will get split between the two new x values in the rediscretized distribution.  The split will be linearly proportional to the distance the old x value is to the new one.

Here's a snippet of R code that I've used (but did not write).

```
Input-
prob: list of probabilities (i.e. in your example y/sum(y)
dr: list of the corresponding values (i.e. x in your example)
newdelta:  The spacing you want between between the new x values (so 9/5 for x=0,1.8,3.6, 5.4,7.2, 9)



resample_any = function(prob, dr, newdelta) {
      oldsize = length(dr)
      max = max(dr)
      newsize = as.integer(max/newdelta+0.9999) + 1
      n=1
      newprob = mat.or.vec(newsize,1)
      for(i in seq(1,newsize,1)){
        p1 = 0; p2 = 0;
        x1= (i-1) * newdelta; 
        x2= i * newdelta;
        mu= 0.0;
        p0= 0.0;
        if (n <= oldsize) {
          for(j in seq(n, oldsize, 1)) {
            if (dr[n] > x2) break;
            mu = mu + prob[j]*dr[j]
            p0 = p0 + prob[j]
            n = n+1
          }
        }

        p1= (mu-p0*x2)/(x1-x2);
        p2= (mu-p0*x1)/(x2-x1);

        newprob[i] = newprob[i] + p1;
        if (i < newsize) {newprob[i+1] = newprob[i+1] + p2}
        else newprob[i] = newprob[i] + p2
      }
      newprob
    }
```

If you've found any material on the subject I'd love to know about it.  This topic is related to the statistical problem of matching moments, but typically goes from a continuous distribution to a discrete one.